# training vs pre-training tag

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Is there any significant difference between [training](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/training) and [pre-training](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pre-training), or we an have one tag for it?